# notify.php file is called multiple times

Tags: php, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I have subscribed for notification. When a user shared any item, notify.php is called and I have written 16 post timeline item. But the biggest problem I am facing is this notify.php called multiple times.

Could any one help me out. It would be very appreciable.

Thanks
Mihir

Comment: Let me look through today's fortune cookie, your answer might be there.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information (like how your `notify.php` looks like) I will have to take a wild guess as to what the most likely problem might be.

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/subscriptions):

> Your service must respond to the API with a 200 OK HTTP status code if no error occurred. If your service responds with an error code, the Mirror API might try to resend the notification to your service.
>
> Note: The connection will time out after 10 seconds. If a long process is required, respond right away and do the process in another thread.

Does your script fulfil these requirements?

Comment: Thank you very much Scarygami. I have two query again. 1. How can I check the service respond as "200" when my notify.php is called? 2. Can I increase execution time of the script using php function "set_time_limit()" ?. Actually my php script has no error as I have checked with error_log file but I am doing much work there like picking color code from a file and post 16 timeline item again. I think it might be due to the execution time. Please suggest.